# Service worker in Gatsby (react.js)

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, gatsby

I am trying to set up a custom service worker for the gatsby app. The build process of my application takes about 7 minutes and the service worker is registered only in production mode, so I am not able to develop fast. It takes minutes to add for example a new `console.log` and check it.
Can I somehow test service worker in development mode?

Comment: If you do not find an answer on Stack Overflow, you might want to open an issue and ask the gatsby developers directly on the github repository: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-plugin-offline . They should know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Gatsby's API for the Service Worker you need to export the function `registerServiceWorker` in `gatsby-browser.js`. The problem is that this function is triggered during the build process when you run `gatsby develop` instead of when you enter the website in your browser. That's why it will not register the Service Worker in you browser (where it needs to be to work).

To fix your issue when you work locally, call the exported function `registerServiceWorker` yourself every time you enter the website in the browser (`onClientEntry` in `gatsby-browser.js`).

I recommend to also wrap it in an if statement to only call it when you're working with it locally. I have a variable `ENABLE_LOCAL_SW = true` in my .env file.

```
// gatsby-browser.js

export const onClientEntry = () => {
  if (process.env.ENABLE_LOCAL_SW) {
    registerServiceWorker();
  }
};

export const registerServiceWorker = () => {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    // Do magic
  }
}
```